# Jmeter: Thread for spcific site to be accessed from Specific slave

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I am planning to use Jmeter in master slave set up  and slaves being in different regions in AWS.

E-commerce application is deployed in single Region (eu-west-2, London) and the site is accessed by users across multiple geographies such as UK and EU using different URLs as shown below traffic distribution

```
https://hostname/site=dummy-uk - 86%    
https://hostname/site=dummy-eu -1%   
https://hostname/site=dummy-de - 4%    
https://hostname/site=dummy-fr -3%   
https://hostname/site=dummy-nl- 3%   
https://hostname/site=dummy-es-3%
```

Traffic distribution for each site URL is available and able to code that in JavaScript so that each site will get % as per defined above.

I want to restrict UK specific site to be accessed from UK specific AWS slave like wise for all slaves.

How to approach for the solution? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) and/or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions, using them you can distinguish JMeter slaves based on region.

So the following construction assuming [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) should be something you're looking for:

- If Controller, condition `"${__machineName()}} == "some machine name from UK region"`

  - UK specific request 1
  - UK specific request 2
- If Controller, condition `"${__machineName()}} == "some machine name from US region"`

  - US specific request 1
  - US specific request 2

See [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) article for more hints if needed

Comment: I can implement above code and put if controller in each Thread group.  however If I am using ultimate thread group and if I have 500 thread allocated to specific thread group, Is it possible to assign specific % of threads to UK slave out of 500 threads, so on so forth?